# VBA point is not found. the point is in picture

Tags: excel, vba

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetClosePrice()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, re As Object, p As String, r As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    p = """pe_details[enter image description here][1]"":""(.*?)"""
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
            .Open "GET", "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuote.jsp?symbol=HAL", False
            .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
            .send
            If .Status = 200 Then
                r = GetValue(re, .responseText, p)
            Else
                r = "Failed connection"
            End If
    End With
    ws.Range("K11").Value = r
End Sub

Public Function GetValue(ByVal re As Object, ByVal inputString As String, ByVal pattern As String) As String
    With re
        .Global = True
        .pattern = pattern
        If .test(inputString) Then  ' returns True if the regex pattern can be matched agaist the provided string
            GetValue = .Execute(inputString)(0).submatches(0)
        Else
            GetValue = "Not found"
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Jugal, try to read this on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: sure i will use it .

Comment: You should definitely ***[read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)*** @Jugal Kishor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want the P/E you can try this:
[image]

```
    Set o = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With o
      .Open "GET", "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/getPEDetails.jsp?symbol=HAL"
      .send
      If .Status = 200 Then
          r = .responseText
      Else
          r = "Failed connection"
      End If
    End With
```

so your 'r' variable will have the json response. Then you need to extract the data from it.